# Laravel - Random password on create

Tags: laravel

I have a method that stores employee data on create however I have defined a default password to be randomly created and hashed. The password isn't stored for some reason.

Any ideas?

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // get company
        $company = Auth::user()->companies()->first();

        // get and validate data
        $storeData = $request->validate([
            'firstname' => 'required',
            'lastname' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'phone' => 'required|numeric|digits:11'
        ]);

        // create employee with validated data
        $employee = $company->employees()->create(array_merge($storeData), [
            'password' => Hash::make(Str::random(40)),
        ]);

        return redirect('/employees/' . $employee->id )
            ->with('success', 'Employee successfully created');
    }
```

Comment: Is your `password` attribute in the `$fillable` in your User Model?

Comment: yes it is in the $fillable array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an typo in your code, try

```php
   $employee = $company->employees()->create(array_merge($storeData, [
            'password' => Hash::make(Str::random(40)),
   ]));
```

The `array_merge` is closed too early and only contains what you have in the `$storeData` array.